# Visual Studio could not install packages

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I installed the first time Visual Studio Community on my Mac an created a Project for an Android App and after I tried to add the "Tweedsharp" package I've got this error. I tried to add other packages or a new or an otherwise Projekt, but I couldn't add any package.

> Could not install package 'TweetSharp-Unofficial 2.3.1.2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Comment: The project has not been updated in 3 years this is not suprising

Comment: My Project or "Tweetsharp"?

Comment: Tweetsharp there have been updates to xamarin since the library was created